Alternator has low initial output
When starting after sitting like over night, the truck starts but the alternator output is ~10.5 volts. The truck runs fine. After 2 to 3 minutes of engine running, the output quickly rises to 14.3 volts. Raising the RPMs does not change the low output. With subsequent stops and restarts it reads 14.3 volts from the get go.
The battery is 2-1/2 year old Walmart Everstart Maxx (made by Interstate). I used my battery load tester and it checks out "good."
Replaced the 8 year old alternator and have the exact same situation.
I removed all 4 grounds, clean the end and body/frame/intake/block contact areas.I even added a new ground from the alternator mounting bracket to body. No difference.
I pulled the negative cable off the battery and did a parasitic drain reading. It was 10 millamps. It's a 1986 Toyota truck with no power anything. Just the ECU,stereo, and clock.
I read a battery can test 'good" but still have a short that can affect alternator.
I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Before anything else, I think you should start with a cold engine and attach a voltmeter directly to the battery terminals, with the meter propped where you can see it from the driver's seat. Then start the truck. See if the direct reading after starting agrees with the instrument panel's voltmeter. If it does not, I would suspect an issue with the instrument cluster or wiring to it, not the battery or alternator.
